# How to use apache websocket on windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, websocket, apache2.2

I need to develop a program that gets some files from the server and use them to draw some graphs on the client side. I was thinking to use Apache 2.2 on my Windows 7 machine and to use html5 to develop the program in a browser (in the beginning ill use client-server to be in the same machine). I was looking for websockets and I found [apache-websocket](https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket) which seemed useful for my case. However, although I believe I followed all the instructions to install it and checked if the library paths are correct, I keep getting these errors:

> mod_websocket.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp_apr_thread_mutex_create referenced in function mod_websocket_method_handler

and similar other lines like that.

IS there anybody knows why I get these errors?

And actually, I have checked other websocket-plugins and they seem to me that they were introduced to be used in unix machines mostly, I couldn’t find much about Windows 7. If you have any other suggestions, including how to install and start to use them, would be appreciated,
Thanks,

Comment: I am currently working on a websocket app for windows. I am using Alchemy. The main advantage here is that you don't have to install Apache. You will have to build it in a .NET though.

Comment: Just i wanted to use Apache server since i wanted to focus on the client program. I thought it would be practical but actually I am stuck right now :/

Comment: Well, either way you have to build backend code. You do realize, websockets are mainly for 2-way communication for things like chat systems. From what little you posted about your project, perhaps you should look at AJAX.